# Advice for a Newbie Wordpress Web Designer/ Themes?

Tags: themes

I am digging into a freelance career and I would like to know what the best advice is out there when it comes to buying themes for clients?

What is the best practice? Themeforest? Bundles? What should be my criteria when choosing themes to develop and offer to clients?

Comment: **Close voted**. Please rework your question and offer details that will help later visitor. In it's current state, there's no "right" answer, that can be marked as solution later on - see the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Firstly, if you have to re-sell themes then you need to be sure that the licence permits it and that you are being open with the client, no buying a theme for $20, claiming it is your own and charging the client $1000.

You should learn how themes work and look towards developing your own to become a web designer, simply re-selling themes makes you a middle man, not a web designer.

An honest approach to this is by selling your services as technical assistance, you have your client pick a theme or you choose one based on their requirements and do the installation and set-up for them, alternatively learn how WordPress themes work and offer your services as a web designer to re-brand and modify the purchased template.

As for template sites, I like Theme Forest however there are loads of them out there however I cannot stress enough, make sure you are not breaking licence or market place usage  terms or you could find yourself in trouble.

Comment: Great advice @frontendjohn, put things into better perspective. Your right about the definition of a web designer, I might look into developing my own themes in the future. For now Ill stick to the basics of a consultant/technical assistance type of service. I appreciate the tips!

Comment: sorry but the theme forest information is not good advice.  The only thing that prohibits you from buying a GPL (which theme forest claims) theme for $20 and selling it for $20,000 is your own conscience and reputation.

Comment: To be fair, I never claimed it was not possible regarding Theme Forest, I have just stressed that it is something that should be considered. My comment at the top is in general and aimed more towards honesty. I know there are many many people who buy and re-sell themes from sites like Theme Forest and I am sure most of them are doing it within the confines of the rules but I feel that simply saying its fine to buy and resell any theme would have been very poor advice, what if theme forest change their policy in a few months and this comes up on Google and not all themes are a free for all?